# ruby, using regex to find something in between two strings

Tags: ruby, regex

Using Ruby + regex, given:

`starting-middle+31313131313@mysite.com`

I want to obtain just: `31313131313`

ie, what is between `starting-middle+` and `mysite.com`

Here's what I have so far:

```
to = 'starting-middle+31313131313@mysite.com'

to.split(/\+/@mysite.com.*/).first.strip
```

Comment: This question is incredibly similar to your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219999/ruby-regex-help) asked two hours later.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Between 1st `+` and 1st `@`:

```
to[/\+(.*?)@/,1]
```

Between 1st `+` and last `@`:

```
to[/\+(.*)@/,1]
```

Between last `+` and last `@`:

```
to[/.*\+(.*)@/,1]
```

Between last `+` and 1st `@`:

```
to[/.*\+(.*?)@/,1]
```

Comment: to[/\+(.*?)@/,1] - The number 1 is for first match found in string ?

Comment: @stack1, yes it is for what is **inside the first `()`**. Just like `.match(//)[1]` or `.match(//).group(1)` in some other languages. Usually you are retrieving the single substring when applying regex, so the `,1` is rather usual in Ruby.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a solution without regex (much easier for me to read):

```
i = to.index("+")
j = to.index("@")
to[i+1..j-1]
```

Comment: this works, but its too many lines of code :) btw, where do you get questions for your codequizzes website ?

Comment: @stack1- I make up all the questions on CodeQuizzes :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution based on regex lookbehind and lookahead.

```
email = "starting-middle+31313131313@mysite.com"
regex = /(?<=\+).*(?=@)/
regex.match(email)
=> #<MatchData "31313131313">
```

### Explanation

1. Lookahead is indispensable if you want to match something followed by something else. In your case, it's a position followed by @, which express as `(?=@)`
2. Lookbehind has the same effect, but works backwards. It tells the regex engine to temporarily step backwards in the string, to check if the text inside the lookbehind can be matched there. In your case, it's a position after `+`, which express as `(?<=\+)`

so we can combine those two conditions together.

```
lookbehind   (what you want)   lookahead
    ↓              ↓             ↓
 (?<=\+)           .*          (?=@)
```

### Reference

[Regex: Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: This is a really well-constructed answer. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you care about readability, i suggest to just use "split", like so:
string.split("from").last.split("to").first or, in your case:

to.split("+").last.split("@").first

use the limit 2 if there are more occurancies of '+' or '@' to only care about the first occurancy:
to.split("+",2).last.split("@",2).first