# Extracting part of email address

Tags: ruby, regex, email

Given:

> thread-reply+xxxxxxxxxxxx@mysite.com

How do I go about getting what's in between the `-` and the `+`, in this case being `reply`?

I'm trying:

```
[/\-(.*?)+/,1]
```

Comment: The plus sign is a special character there. You have to escape it: `\+`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape `+`:

```
[/\-(.*?)\+/,1]
```

Answer (score 2):

The following is a general regex syntax for a pattern that should work:

```
^([^-]*)-([^+]*)\+.*$
```

[Rubular says it works](http://rubular.com/r/pqvFTBA6XR).  Look at the match captures.

Explanation:

```
^        // the start of the input
([^-]*) // the 'thread' part
-        // a literal '-'
([^+]*)  // the 'reply' part
\+       // a literal '+'
.*       // the rest of the input
$        // the end
```

Comment: Hmm that doesn't work. I'm trying to get thread, and I did: return to[/^\-/,1] errors

Comment: @AnApprentice, I don't know ruby.  What does that mean?