# Regex catch multiple match look behind look ahead

Tags: regex, ruby

This is extended question from this [ruby, using regex to find something in between two strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4218986/ruby-using-regex-to-find-something-in-between-two-strings/4219038)

So i'd like to catch multiple of this username

Text (1 line)

`starting-middle+31313131313@mysite.com starting-middle+4141414141@mysite.com`

Result

`["31313131313", "4141414141"]`

I tried this `(?<=\+).*(?=@)` but it will take the last look ahead character, so the result like `31313131313@mysite.com starting-middle+41414141`

https://rubular.com/r/3mn5t1pYffCC7C

Comment: Try `/(?<=\+)[^+@]+(?=@)/`. See [Rubular](https://rubular.com/r/7p38LVrpFVa73d). If the characters between `+` and `@` must be digits, `/(?<=\+)\d+(?=@)/` See [Rubular](https://rubular.com/r/mcB9ED84DOBPMj). I assume you want at least one character between `+` and `@`; hence `+` rather than `*`.

Comment: i think you have to use lazy quantifier `(?<=\+).*?(?=@)` instead `[^+@]`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a lookbehind, you could match the `+` and use `\K` to forget what is matched so far.

Then use a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) to match any character except `@` or a whitespace char and use the positive lookahead to assert an `@` on the right.

```
\+\K[^\s@]+(?=@)
```

**Explanation**

- `\+` Match `+`
- `\K` Clear the match buffer
- `[^\s@]+` Match 1+ times any char except a whitespace char or `@` *(Or use `\d+` to match only digits)*
- `(?=@)` Positive lookahead, assert `@` directly to the right of the current position

[Regex demo](https://rubular.com/r/GkO3V1PIIAGh3I)